Nonnegativity of the fractional heat kernel
It is quite well-known that for $\alpha \in(0,2]$, if we define
$$p_t(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{ix\cdot \xi} e^{-t|\xi|^\alpha}d\xi,$$
then $p_t$ is a probability density function by using Levy-Khinchin's formula (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2626)
Somehow, I am curious how to show this without probabilistic language. How can we show that $p_t(x)\geq 0$? It is easy to show that $p_t(x)$ is real since
$$ \mathrm{Im}\, p_t(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \sin(x\cdot \xi) e^{-t|\xi|^\alpha} d\xi=0$$
because of the oddness of the integral. So it suffices to show that
$$p_t(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \cos(x\cdot \xi) e^{-t|\xi|^\alpha} d\xi=0$$
Once it is proved, then it is easy to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p_t(x)dx=1$ since $e^{0}=1$.
My trial was to use dyadic decomposition together with the monotone decay of $e^{-|\xi|^\alpha}$, but somehow it is not that easy to control those if $0<\alpha<2$.
Thank you.

I found that there was some discussion in discussion, however, I just want to show that $p_t$ is nonnegative.


Can you show how you get positivity in 1 D ?

I would use spherical coordinates and do the integral on the sphere first, which would give a Bessel function, then the radial integral would be similar to the one dimensional case.

@Medo At first, I thought that 1D case is easy but it seems that it is not since I didn't consider the case $|x|$ to be large. I followed your suggestion and I got the expression in terms of Bessel function. However, due to the term $s^{d/2}$, I am not sure how to control compare the area of the region even though I have exponential decay term...

Is there supposed to be a $t$ somewhere in the definition of $p_t(x)$? Also, I don't think your $p_t(x)$ is normalized as written. You'd need to have ${1/(2\pi)}^d$ as the prefactor instead of ${1/(2\pi)^{d/2}}$.

@JohnBarber Thank you for pointing out typo. I changed it.
